# WIndows + Openconnect, cannot browse internet

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, cisco-anyconnect, openconnect

I need to connect to a third-party Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

In my Windows PC, am using CLI `openconnect` client from https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect

The VPN works perfectly fine, however it blocks navigation to other Internet sites.
I suppose that all Internet traffic is forwarded through the VPN, and this should not happen.

(Please notice that I have exactly the same issue with Cisco AnyConnect Client; this is the reason why I tried with OpenConnect).

Inside the VPN, my IP is `10.127.94.xxx` and I have to reach two different servers located at `10.128.230.yyy` and `172.25.98.zzz`

So I ask, how can I set up openconnect/routes so that the VPN is used only for these two IP's?

Thank you.

Comment: Check if the client Apps and/or the target VPN have split tunnel enabled

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Googling, I found out that there exist a tool "vpn-slice" that allows split tunnelling in Linux; however it does not work in Windows :(

Comment: NCP Secure Entry permits split tunnel.  It works in Windows

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to enable "split tunnel" with OpenConnect. Take the default script `vpnc-script-win.js`, it is inside `c:\Programs\OpenConnect` folder; find where the environment "env" is loaded: https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/blob/master/vpnc-script-win.js#L25

and there add `CISCO_SPLIT_INC` configuration:

```
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC") = 3;   // how many IP's to reach in VPN network
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_0_ADDR") = '10.128.230.yyy'; // first IP
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_0_MASK") = '255.255.255.255';
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_0_MASKLEN") = 0;
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_1_ADDR") = '172.25.98.zzz'; // second IP
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_1_MASK") = '255.255.255.255';
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_1_MASKLEN") = 0;
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_2_ADDR") = '172.25.68.www'; // DNS
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_2_MASK") = '255.255.255.255';
env("CISCO_SPLIT_INC_2_MASKLEN") = 0;
```

Hope this can help somebody.